# sudo access vs wheel group

Tags: permissions, sudo, users, group

I am just a little bit confused here. When you are asked to give a user sudo access to the machine. Should I just add the user to the wheel group.

```
# usermod -aG wheel bob
```

Or let's say there is no wheel group or it is deleted for some reason.

then how can I grant bob sudo access to the machine.When I did

```
# which sudo
```

I get the result: `/usr/bin/sudo`

So can I do the following line then:

```
bob     ALL=/usr/bin/sudo
```

But then I changed to user bob after and tried to execute

```
# sudo iptables -L
```

and then it gives me that error message:

> Sorry, user bob is not allowed to execute '/sbin/iptables -L' as root

And so am not sure how to give sudo access to the machine to a user if the group wheel is not there. And according to my knowledge

```
bob       ALL=ALL    ALL
```

Basically makes bob have the same power like root which is not good right.

Another question I have is how to make all users on the system able to execute the last command. Do I have to create a group and then add all users to this group or is there another way?

Comment: `bob ALL = /sbin/iptables -L`.  See `man sudoers`.

Comment: I know that but I want to give bob sudo access not just iptables -L

Comment: If you "want to give bob sudo access", that means that bob *will have* the "same power like root". What exactly do you want? You want bob to have sudo access, but restrict certain root powers?

Comment: Please note this should be `bob ALL=(ALL) ALL`, you're missing a set of parens in there... Check if your sudoers file has an entry for `%wheel`, sometimes it's commented out...

Answer (score 20):

When the wheel group membership gives an user full root access through sudo, it is normally configured like this in the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
%wheel    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Meaning: "any members of group `wheel` on `ALL` hosts can sudo to `ALL` user accounts to run `ALL` commands." So it's exactly the same as your "bad" line:

```
bob      ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

If you want to give an user (or a group) full access to a specific other user account and nothing else, you can do it this way:

```
user     ALL=(targetuser) ALL
# or
%group   ALL=(targetuser) ALL
```

Then, the user(s) can do

```
$ sudo -u targetuser command
```

to quickly execute individual commands as the target user, or

```
$ sudo -iu targetuser
```

to get a shell as the target user, with the exact same environment the target user would get when logging in directly.

For historical reasons, some people reflexively use

```
sudo su - targetuser
```

for the second purpose. This would require giving the user(s) in question at least access to run the `

```
su - targetuser
```

command as root, and it will be more difficult to piece together from the logs what the user actually did. This command was useful back when `sudo` did not have the `-i` option, but I think that option has been there for about 15 years by now.

Answer (score -1):

1. `visudo` add a line as: 
   `user1 ALL=/bin/cat, /etc/shadow` this allows a user1 to read only /etc/shadow using a `sudo`. It means, you will not able to run other commands than `cat` and read no other files than `/etc/shadow` using `sudo` as well. If you type `user1 ALL=/etc/shadow`, it will be useless, because there should at least some tool to read this file (it's just an example, you don't have to read the `/etc/shadow/` file)

> by the way, 'ALL' means the list of commands to execute and files to interact. By default there is ALL=(ALL) next to the *root user* that means literally all commands and files.

2. If you want to make the `last` command (or any other commands) executable by all users, you can make a hard link to the public directory (`/usr/bin`) and change the permission of this command (file) by `chmod +0001 /usr/bin/last`. But `last` command I guess is executable by all users by default.

To check the list of commands your user is able to run currently, use `sudo -l`.

Comment: Your `sudo`ers line is wrong. Adding `/etc/shadow` like that means the user can run `/etc/shadow` as a program. It's also wrong because ordinary users should not be allowed to read `/etc/shadow`; you're breaking the authentication security here.

Comment: @roaima angry user, hi there again. I mentioned in parentheses that you don't have to read `/etc/shadow`. Just drink a glass of water and calm down. Thanks for -1, by the way. Appreciate it. Everything I posted above is correct. Wanna check, go ahead.

Comment: J.Doe, I'm not angry. I've read your complaint and taken time to recheck carefully whether your `sudoers` line works as I've warned or as you've described. Here are my findings. As written, your line permits both `/bin/cat` and `/etc/shadow` to be run (as any user) by `user1`. (1) This means no file is secure from `user1` as they can read - and therefore copy - every file on the system (2) `/etc/shadow` isn't a program so although you've listed it as a possible executable it cannot be run.

Comment: In order for the command to work as you've described, I think you probably shouldn't have included the comma after `/bin/cat`. But it's still a massive security issue