# default user privileges, root and sudo/admin/wheel groups on ubuntu18.04

Tags: ubuntu, users, group

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and noticed a few things:

1. My default user (the one configures right after installation) belongs to sudo group with the following permissions: ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
2. My root user doesn't have a password
3. On /etc/sudoers file there is a group called admin: %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
   but its not listed in /etc/group

my questions are:

1. Why my default user belongs to sudo group? its basically means I have 2 root users. Is that true?
2. How can I change the default groups a new user will belongs to
3. I read here:
   [sudo access vs wheel group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416633/sudo-access-vs-wheel-group)

but didn't understand the difference between ALL=(ALL) ALL and ALL=(ALL:ALL)

4. Why admin group appears in /etc/sudoers but not in /etc/group
5. My primary goal is to create a guest user which will not be able to do much on the system (modify filesystem on his separate dedicated partition only) and an admin account with strong password.
   Is that means that I have to delete my "default installed" user and create a new one or just deleting him from the sudo group will be enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Ubuntu's philosophy to disable root logins by not giving a password to root. I suppose this is so that any login leaves a log entry that identifies a specific user rather than root, so that there is a throat to choke ("hutcruchi, you need to get better at protecting your password!"). Or perhaps to make it harder to guess how to logon - you have to guess not only the password, but also the user account.

Side remark: Not everybody agrees with this philosophy.

Thus:

1. Somebody needs to be the admin. Might as well be the default user.
2. In `/etc/login.defs`, set `USERGROUPS_ENAB` to `no`. In `/etc/default/useradd`, set `GROUP` to the value you want.
3. `(ALL)` is the **target** user of a sudo command, i.e. the user you can become. `(ALL:ALL)` specifies the target group after the colon. `ALL` after the closing parenthesis is the **action** that can be performed under sudo; for example, `ALL=(ALL) /bin/ls` means that the ls command can be run as any user. Obviously, ALL means any group/user/action. This is documented in the sudoers manual page under the paragraph *Runas_Spec*.
4. I need to guess, but am pretty certain that this is so you can create an admin group for users with admin privileges, rather than the default `sudo`, whose name might baffle the average observer.
5. You could keep the default user, give it a strong password and use it for admin work. If you don't plan to use the default user, remove it (but first create the admin user). Or simply, when you install the system, name the default user "admin" and, again, give it a strong password.